# JavaScript - Replacing "no-js" class with "js" class not working?

Tags: javascript, html, class, replace, classname

I placed a class in my `<html>` element called "no-js". This indicates that the user isn't using javascript, (whether it be disabled or blocked). And then, in a script file I created, I want to revoke "no-js" and inject "js" so that I can determine if the user is using javascript or not via classes. I tried using the `replace()` method by querying the html tag, but it isn't working. Here's what I have:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
if(html.className == "no-js") {
    html.className.replace("no-js", "js"); // user has JS enabled
}
```

There are no errors in Google Chrome or Firefox's bug console, but neither is it changing `no-js` to `js`. I would use the `<noscript>` tag but I like to keep the markup side of it clean.

Comment: It doesn't do the replacement in place. You have to do `html.className = html.className.replace("no-js", "js");`

Comment: html.classList.remove( 'no-js' ); html.classList.add( 'js' );

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`replace` *returns* the new string, it doesn't modify the original.

Try `html.className = 'js'`, since you've already established that it's the only class name with your `if` statement.

EDIT: Also, the `<html>` tag is already available as `document.documentElement`.

```
document.documentElement.className = 'js';
```

That's all you need, really. No `if` statement, no variable, nothing.

Comment: Oh yeah! I thought that would *add* `js` to the html, not replace. But to do that I would have to do `+=`. It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is indeed correct, but this way will replace all classes of the `<html>`, not only `.no-js`.

This little script will do the same thing, but will instead search only for the `no-js` class and rewrite it.

```
document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/g, '') + ' js ';
```

Took script from here, very simple!
http://snipplr.com/view/63895/remove-nojs-class-from-html-tag-add-js-class/

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to assign the `html.className` to the new value:

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
if(html.className == "no-js") {
    html.className = html.className.replace("no-js", "js"); // user has JS enabled
}
```

Comment: Ah, this would work too, but the other answer is simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With a little regex

```js
(function(html) {
  html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/, 'js')
})(document.documentElement);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
 
</body>
</html>
```